# Explain `infercase` option

Tags: ins-completion

I don't understand what `:h infercase` is supposed to do. I tried out some scenarios, but still can't figure out the differences between when it is turned off and on. Can someone explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
set ignorecase
set noinfercase
```

and you have a file that somewhere contains the word "WORLD" and you type

```
wor<C-P>
```

The part `wor` will be completed to `WORLD`.

If you enable `infercase` and try the same, `wor` will be completed to `world`.

So Vim does a case-insensitive completion, but infers the case from the characters you already typed. As mentioned in the docs, this only works with `ignorecase`.

BTW: `Wo` is completed to `World`, but `wO` is completed to `wOrld`.

Comment: Well, using `:set infercase` then removes the problem I had with `:h dictionary`. In the dictionary, there are words that are non-capitalized. So, when I wanted to use it as title or something, it didn't work. But using `:set infercase` has another problem. I could complete `INT_MAX` from `int_<C-n>`, now it will be autocompleted to `int_max` which I don't want. It's a drag.